# How to create connecting faces to make intersections using Geometry nodes in Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes

Here I have created a grid mesh to make a city like street pattern. I used curve line to generate the streets and trim curve to leave space for intersections. However I have no idea how To make the intersection at the moment. My idea was that if I could connect the vertices of the ends, then I could use fill curve to generate the intersections. Can someone pls help me with this?
[Initial Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4YT4.png)
[image: How I want the intersections to be]
[image: 3]

Answer (score 5):

If you put a curve perimeter around instanced, filleted curve-quadrilaterals, then the fill algorithm interprets them as holes:

[image]

.. maybe that would be a starting point?

Comment: very elegant solution. this fill curve is really awesome.

Comment: wow thanks. I'll try this out. Sry i forgot to upload my node network in the question, I've updated now. I'm trying to make dynamic road connections which would work with roads in all axes. Hence I started experimenting with this grid and got stuck there